# WSO2 ESB 4.9 - fire and forgot is not working with OUT_ONLY

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am newbie to WSO2 ESB, so far everything is OK. 
I started exploring fire and forgot feature, looks like this can be used as below to invoke async calls to end points.

```
 <property name="CHANNEL_COD" value="999"/>
 <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
 <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
```

But when tested the API with above code, still ESB invoking the end point in syncronous. Tried this approach with call and send mediators.

Would anybody please help me is there any link I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

With ESB 4.8.1 :

If ClientApiNonBlocking property is not set, send mediator should be asynchronous.

Because of FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED, 202 http status code will be sended back at the end of IN mediation (ie : the message has been delivered to your endpoint, without waiting for the response)

If it takes several seconds to send the message to the endpoint, the caller will receive 202 status code AFTER that.

If you want this status code to be sent ASAP, you can use clone mediator and move send mediator inside clone's target

Comment: This approach is working just for one service in standalone but I have couple of services in service chaining pattern and I want to call async service before and after execution of each service in service chaining. Problem I am facing with this approach is once the send is called as first target in InSequence then the controller is going to out sequence immediately and controller is not going to the service chaining configures as receive attribute in the async service

Comment: If you need service chaining, you mustn't set OUT_ONLY to true. Just avoid to send back the response to the caller in your out sequence (don't use <send/> nor <respond/>)

Comment: Thanks Jean. My confusion here is how the response goes back to the caller If I do not use send in out sequence. In my case I need to call service-1 in aysnc, then need to call service-2 using receive attribute in service1 send, then need to call service-3 using receive attribute in service 2 send. This is the way I am implementing service chaining pattern and finnally I need to send the response of service-3 to the caller. Please suggest me the approach to implement this.

Comment: So, don't use OUT_ONLY and don't use FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED : you do not want to send back an http 202 accpeted, but a real response to the caller

Comment: Thanks Jean. Would it be possible for you to send sample API configuration file to implement async call implementation with 3 sample services and 2nd one is async and 1,3rd are sync. Many thanks